# Weird definition of Kodaira-Spencer map (What's a relative Kähler differential on a manifold?)

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, moduli-space

When I was reading ["Advances in Moduli Theory" by Shimizu Yuji](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=N7zc8cLP_aoC&pg=PR6&lpg=PR6&dq=moduli+yuji+shimizu&source=bl&ots=3jmXkFRZ88&sig=YbOLVTforJjMVZO6cHtgtbEZeAQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ivtCU6qwO8uz0QHIloGYBA&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=moduli%20yuji%20shimizu&f=false), I´ve found a weird way of writing the Kodaira-Spencer map $\rho$. For a given analytic family of complex compact manifolds $\pi :\mathcal{V} \twoheadrightarrow \mathcal{W} $, the author uses the notation $$\rho : \Theta_\mathcal{W} \longrightarrow R^1 \pi_* \Theta_{\mathcal{V/W}}$$ for the Kodaira-Spencer map given in each fiber by $\rho_w : \Theta_w \longrightarrow H^1(V_w,\Theta_{\mathcal{V_w}})$, such that $\Theta$ is the sheaf of holomorphic tangent vector fields. **However what´s $\Theta_\mathcal{V/W}$ in the context of manifolds????!!!!**

In scheme theory, $\Theta_{X/Y} = Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X} (\Omega^1_{X/Y}, \mathcal{O}_X)$, however for manifolds what´s the correct definition of relative differentials?

**Is it possible to define $\Omega^1_{X/Y}$ for manifolds as people do for schemes??**

Trying the analogous approach for some $f: X \rightarrow Y$ would lead in considering the map $\Delta_{X/Y}: X \longrightarrow X \times_Y X$ and, then pulling back the cotangent space $T^{*}(\Delta_{X/Y} (X))$. Apparently the action of pulling back and picking the dual commutes (I think so, but maybe it's wrong), so it would be enough to test if $\Delta_{X/Y}^* (T(\Delta_{X/Y})) \cong TX /Ker(f_*)$, however for a proper surjective submersion $f$ (as in the original case $\pi$) it looks like that $\Delta_{X/Y}^* (T(\Delta_{X/Y})) \cong TX$ (when drawing some "sketches", considering that $f$ is a locally trivial fibration).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\Theta_\mathcal{V/W}$ is the sheaf of holomorphic sections of the holomorphic vector bundle that is the kernel of the differential of the projection $T\mathcal V \to T\mathcal W$.  What relative differential are you asking about?

Comment: @EricO.Korman Thanks for the definition. The sheaf of relative differentials in schemes is just $\Delta_{X/Y}^{-1} (\mathcal{I/ I^2})$, where $\mathcal{I}$ is the ideal sheaf defined by $\Delta (X)$.

Comment: Unfortunately I know hardly any scheme theory so I'm not sure what the corresponding differential geometric notion is.  Is there a part on "Advances in Moduli Theory" that references this?

Comment: @EricO.Korman No, there is not. But I think it will be just the dual to the sheaf of relative tangent vectors (the one that you said in your definition). However I do not know if using the sheaf of holomorphic functions (or the sheaf of smooth functions) instead of the structure sheaf of the scheme will result in the analogous version of the sheaf of relative differentials, maybe we have to use GAGA.

Comment: @EricO.Korman Furthermore, where did you see the definition that I said in the first comment? I tried looking at a lot of books but could not find.

Comment: The definition of $\Theta_\mathcal{V/W}$?  That's eq (1.5) on p. 6 of Advances of in Moduli Theory.

Comment: @EricO.Korman Ops, I need to sleep more.

Comment: I just want to mention that your definition of relative differentials would also work for manifolds, as long as you regard your (smooth) manifold as a locally ringed space with the sheaf of smooth functions. Of course, that's equivalent to what Eric wrote down.

Comment: @Sanchez  Ok, but then how do I check that $\Delta_{X/Y}^* (T(\Delta_{X/Y}(X))) \cong TX /Ker(f_*)$ holds?

Comment: @Sanchez Furthermore I would like to point that regular functions behaves more like holomorphic functions and not like smooth functions, so I don't think that trivially the algebraic version must be equivalent to the differential geometric.

Comment: @user40276, not really - the thing is people generally learn about locally ringed space when they do scheme theory, and rarely looked at smooth manifolds this way. I am not 100% certain, but let's say I'm 90% certain, that for your question it should work in both smooth category and holomorphic category.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to consider the fiber product but it is easy to define $\Omega_{X/Y}^1$: it is just the dual of $\Theta_{X/Y}$.  The complex $\Omega_{X/Y}^\bullet = \Lambda^\bullet \Omega_{X/Y}^1$ has a natural differential, the vertical $\partial$ operator.  This is defined on p. 116 of "Advances in Moduli Theory" as acting on holomorphic functions as the $\partial$ operator on the total space $X$ followed by restriction $\Omega_X^1 \to \Omega_{X/Y}^1$.  I think this must be the relative differential you're asking about.

There is also a more intrinsic way to get this.  The space $\Theta_{X/Y}$ is a holomorphic Lie algebroid via the Lie bracket of vector fields and the action on holomorphic functions by differentiation.  In general if $A$ is any Lie algebroid then the dual exterior algebra $\Lambda^\bullet A^*$ becomes a dga with the differential given by
$$
(d_A \mu)(v_0,\ldots,v_k) = \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i v_i \cdot \mu(v_0,\ldots,\hat{v_i},\ldots,v_k) \\+ \sum_{i<j} (-1)^{i+j}\mu([v_i,v_j], v_0, \ldots, \hat{v_i},\ldots,\hat{v_j},\ldots,v_k),
$$
where $\mu \in \Lambda^k A^*, v_0,\ldots,v_k \in A$.

Comment: Thanks, but I've never studied Lie grupoids and Lie algebroids properly. Furthermore, my intention in considering the fiber product was to mimetize the definition of the sheaf of relative differentials for schemes (that I've defined in the comments above) but using smooth (or holomorphic) functions instead of regular functions (the algebraic version of holomorphic function). In summary, I want to know if the definitions (the algebraic and differential geometric) agree or not.

Comment: Thanks again , but is "dga" differential graded algebra?

Comment: Correct, "dga" means differential graded algebra.  This is really a mild Lie algebroid, the point is that when you have some $\mathcal O_X$ module with a Lie bracket (in this case the usual Lie bracket of vector fields) and some compatible action on $\mathcal O_X$ (in this case differentiation of holomorphic functions by holomorphic vector fields), the exterior algebra on the dual has a canonical differential.